# Conforming a generic type to a protocol in a Swift extension

Tags: generics, swift, protocols

I'm trying to make a Swift generic type conform to a protocol *in an extension*. This is the type:

```
enum Maybe<T>{
    case Nothing
    case Something(T)

    init(){
        self = .Nothing
    }

    init(_ something: T){
        self = .Something(something)
    }

}
```

The protocol I want it to conform is `NilLiteralConvertible`

If I try in an extension, I get a bunch of crazy errors:

```
extension Maybe<T>: NilLiteralConvertible{

}
```

I can only implement it if I declare in main definition of `Maybe<T>`. What the heck???

```
enum Maybe<T>: NilLiteralConvertible{
    case Nothing
    case Something(T)

    init(){
        self = .Nothing
    }

    init(_ something: T){
        self = .Something(something)
    }


    // NilLiteralConvertible
    static func convertFromNilLiteral() -> Maybe<T> {

        return Maybe<T>()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for an extension of a class/struct/enum using generics is:

```
extension Maybe : NilLiteralConvertible {    
    static func convertFromNilLiteral() -> Maybe {
        return .Nothing
    }
}
```

so you don't have to specify the generic type `T`, it's already declared in the main definition. If you specify it, it's like you are defining a new generic type

Comment: How's the implementation supposed to work? I tried the following example (with IntegerLiteralConvertible) and can't get it to work:

`extension Maybe : IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    
    static func convertFromIntegerLiteral(value: IntegerLiteralType) -> Maybe{
        return Maybe<Int>(value)
    }
}`

The compiler complains that T is not identical to Int. :-?

Comment: For `NilLiteralConvertible`, see updated answer. As for `IntegerLiteralConvertible`, I wouldn't know... what would you want to do with the integer? you cannot use as an associated value, because the enum uses a generic, so you cannot make the assumption that it's integer-compatible

Comment: I was thinking if there was a way to a specific instantiation of a generic type (say Maybe<Int>) conform to a protocol, in this case IntegerLiteralConvertible. Is this possible?